# How do you echo a Wordpress title inside of a checkbox input value?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using custom post types and meta data and need to define the value of a form checkbox to be the title of the post.

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="activityType" value="'.the_title().'" />';
```

Calling this inside of the loop seems like it should work. Not much luck passing it through though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_title` will echo the title instead of returning it, you can work around this by ending the PHP Block and using `the_title` inline

```
?><input type="checkbox" name="activityType" value="<?=the_title();?>" /><?php
```

Or set the `$echo` argument of `the_title` to `false` to return the value

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="activityType" value="'.the_title('','',false).'" />';
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

Comment: I used your second solution successfully. Thank you! I'll be accepting this as the answer once the time limit passes.

Comment: You could also replace `the_title()` with `get_the_title()`.

Comment: @DavidGard Slightly slower, as you need to get the ID then.

Comment: @DamonGant - No you don't. If `get_the_title()` is being used in The Loop (which I believe is the case, as `the_title()` only works in The Loop), you don't need to pass it any parameters and the ID is gathered from the global `$post`. In fact if you look at the source you'll see that `the_title()` actually references `get_the_title()` (`wp-includes/post-template.php`, line 43 on WP 3.8) and then carries out further logic, making it slower.

Comment: @DavidGard heh, should have known, WordPress code, all over the place again.

Comment: @DamonGant - Yep! I can see why they have done it that way, to make it easier in general for a broad range of users. But yes, if you were starting from scratch you could make it a lot more efficient, though I would suggest at the expense of ease of use.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the title outside of The Loop you need to use 
[get_the_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)

The documentation explain's it [the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

Regards

Comment: False. The form is in the loop, you just can't use `the_title` for composing a string without extra arguments.

Comment: I said, if you want it outside of The loop you use get_the_title, i didn't tell him which one to use, because i didn't know it it was inside of the loop or outside, just to clarify his doubts. I don't know why you should down vote, but it's ok.

Comment: Even if it's in The Loop I'd still use `get_the_title()`, as it's faster. Although you're only talking a tiny amount of time, so even if you list 20 posts per page, I doubt the user would notice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
echo get_the_title($ID);
```

This function will return the title of a post for a given post ID. If the post is protected or private, the word "Protected: " or "Private: " will be prepended to the title. It can be used inside or outside of The Loop. If used outside the loop an ID must be specified.

Read : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: If you are using `get_the_title()` in The Loop you don't even need to pass the `$ID`, as it is gathered automatically from the global $post. This is the quickest way of getting the Title.